# How can I break up long words instead of overflowing?

Tags: html, css

How can I stop [this text](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/464119/kuzando/overflow.html) from overflowing?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.sticky
{
    background-color: #FCFC80;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 135px;
}
.sticky .edit
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    color:Black;    
    background-color:blue;
    height:90px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:90px;
    border-collapse:collapse;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="note44" class="sticky">
<div id="text44" class="edit" title="Click to edit" style="">A very long word: abcdefasdfasfasd</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* word-wrap is supported in most browsers?

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the desired output should be, but if you want to hyphenate the word, you can use `&shy;`, that is, replace `"abcdefasdfasfasd"`, with say, `abcdef&shy;asdfasfasd`.

You could also have a look at the [overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Answer (score 0):

does [justify](http://www.css3.com/css-text-justify/) do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSS property called word-wrap. Give it the attribute "break-word" and you should be good to go.

```
.break-word {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Source: [Web Designer Wall - Force text to wrap](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap/)

Answer (score 0):

The css mentioned above won't work in all browser's as it's non-standard.
When I run into this I usually use php's wordwrap function, but that's no good if you're not using php.

Two things which need to be pointed out:
You've defined the height of the second element twice in the css.
If you wrap text inside an element with a defined height, it could well overflow, and cause you a new set of problems.